# how to set the label postion from portrait to landscape in a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am doing application where i have taken two views Portrait and Landscape. i am creating a label programitically and calling it by parameter passing.As i want the position of the label to be changed in the landscapeView so i am taking two views.Instead i want to do in a SingleView

instead of using two views i want to have only one view and set the label position accordingly in portrait and landscape.

so please suggest me how to have only one view and change the textLabel position  according to the view..please suggest me with sample code.

At present i am using the below code

```
[self.portraitView addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(450,140,60,20):@"Ratings:"]];      
[self.landscapeView addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(600,140,60,20):@"Ratings:"]];

-(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)frame :(NSString*)labelTitle {
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
     myLabel.text = labelTitle;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your UILabel *myLabel a class variable by declaring it in your .h file.
2. Call the createLabel method in the viewDidLoad method of your viewController based on the correct device orientation.

-(void) viewDidLoad

```
{
       UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation

if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
           CGRect frame = CGRectMake(450,140,60,20);
else
           CGRect frame = CGRectMake(600,140,60,20);

        myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
         myLabel.text = labelTitle;     
}
```

1. Reset the frame in this method

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

```
{
     if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandScape)
          {      
              mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(600,140,60,20);  //your landscape frame
              mylabel.text = @"Ratings:";
          }
    else
       {
          mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(450,140,60,20); // your portrait frame
          mylabel.text = @"Ratings:";
       }
}
```

You will need to dig around a little bit for covering all the possible orientations in this method.

Cheers!!!

Comment: after if statement Wat code i should add? give me sample code

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves the issue or update comment if the problem still persists.

Comment: thanks for ur response...but its showing unused variable frame and undeclared of LableTitle...And also i am using parameter passing in my code because..i need to create many Lable Text in my view..so i am using parameter passing as i have many other Text to be created manually..

Comment: Hey because you want to access your labels from different places in your class. You have to have as many class variables as you have labels. You can't avoid it. You don't need to reset the text again and again. Set it for any orientations and it's going to remain the same. Only the labelFrame is going to change based on the orientation. Also set label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter for all the labels so that upon change of frame the text centers itself.

Answer (score 0):

in your code there is a method called

```
     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandScape)
//set label frame here
}
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(650,170,60,20):@"Reviews:"]];  Should i place the above code here?And also its giving warning to return a value...Is the above code correct or shd i  just set the frame..?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following two methods in your viewcontroller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

In `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method, set the required frame to the label instance.

Comment: Ok where i shd add the following code    [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(650,140,60,20):@"Ratings:"]];

Comment: Please make a class member for UILabel. Allocate that instance and add that as subview to the main view. When rotating, just set the frame to the UILabel instance.

Comment: Actually i dont want to create a single LAble Text. In my application i will creating some 10 Label Text in different frame position..so i am using parameter passing in the above code..but why need to create a class member for UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the labels frame in the `layoutSubviews` method of the `UILabel`'s superview and check the superviews bounds or the interface orientation to determine the appropriate frame for the label. If you also use `autoresizingMask` on the `UILabel` correctly, the transition will be animated nicely.

Also: why do you use two views? instead of applying different layouts to one?

Comment: can i have sample code as i am new to i am new to iphone development